# How to flash SPI NOR and read back from the SPI Nor - Microzed Zynq from Uboot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

I am trying to read the kernel image from the mmc card and flash it on the SPI Nor flash. My kernel image is uImage only.

So, I read the kernel image from mmc card and put that into the memory address - 0x8000.

```
Zynq> fatload mmc 0 0x8000 $kernel_image
```

I can see that by running

```
md 0x8000.
```

Now, I want to copy this data from RAM to QSPI flash.

I did the following.

```
sf update 0x8000 0 ${kernel_size}
```

Now, I believe it has read the contents from 0x8000 and has put in SPI Flash at the offset address - 0x0

Now, I am reading back from flash at a different RAM address - 0x3000000

```
>sf read 0x3000000 0 ${kernel_size}
```

Similarly, I am loading device tree image on to the RAM.

```
#fatload mmc 0 0x8000 ${devicetree_image}
```

now, I read back.

```
#md 0x8000 ${devicetree_image}
```

Now, I am writing device tree to the flash.

```
#sf update 0x8000 0x700000 ${devicetree_size}
#sf read 0x2A00000 0x700000 ${devicetree_size}
```

Now, I am checking the device tree on the RAM.

```
md 0x2A00000 ${devicetree_size}
```

Now, I am booting from the newly read RAM address -

```
bootm 0x3000000 - 0x2A00000

Zynq> bootm 0x3000000 - 0x2A00000
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

what am I doing wrong here?

```
Zynq> iminfo 0x3000000

## Checking Image at 03000000 ...
Unknown image format!


Zynq> iminfo 0x8000

## Checking Image at 00008000 ...
   FIT image found
Bad FIT image format!
```

After writing device tree, I see that 0x3000000 has nothing. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: `bootm` expects kernel image processed by mkimage. Try `bootz` if you use zImage. And what does `md 0x3000000` show? Post just the first few lines.

Comment: also show the output from the `iminfo 0x8000` and `iminfo 0x3000000` commands ...

Comment: Actually, when I have read device tree in the memory, I see that the kernel image is none in the address 0x3000000

Comment: My kernel image is uImage only. I have updated the question in details now.

Comment: try reading [this](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/uboot/doc/uImage.FIT/howto.txt) ... it might give you some clues